Обойти запрет на SELECT из таблицы MS SQL Server
Стоит задача в учебных целях получить доступ к базе данных и вывести содержимое одной таблицы.
Есть сервер с развернутым MS SQL Server 2016. На нем размещена база данных с пометкой "только для чтения". В этой базе есть две таблицы - одна доступна всем, а у второй стоит запрет на SELECT для всех, кто находится в группе public. Соответственно, нет возможности узнать, что хранится в данной таблице, однако есть данные о количестве колонок и об их типах.
Подскажите, возможно ли каким-то образом обойти данное ограничение и вывести содержимое недоступной таблицы? Возможно, есть еще какие-то способы кроме брутфорса пароля администратора базы?

А почему просто не использовать учётку, которая НЕ входит в группу public? Если верить вашему описанию, у неё будет доступ к таблице.

@Akina, на сервер могу войти только под учеткой юзера, который состоит в public. Задача заключается в том, чтобы имея на руках только учетку пользователя, которому запрещен Select из указанной таблицы, как-то получить из нее данные. Назначить себе права, естественно, я также не могу)

"которому запрещен Select из указанной таблицы, как-то получить из нее данные" - и в чем же смысл запрета тогда по-вашему? ))
